# Access.adp (2010) and SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, performance, permissions, ms-access-2010

We are using Access .adp (Access 2010) frontend in combination with SQL Server 2014 backend. At the moment we have a big performance problem with the SQL function `permissions()`. We have ca. 400 Users on our application. The logon takes 50+ Seconds for an normal user. Sysadmins logon takes 3 seconds. Do you have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft [seem to have a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/permissions-transact-sql) for this problem:

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use `fn_my_permissions` and `Has_Perms_By_Name` instead. Continued use of the `PERMISSIONS` function may result in slower performance.

Comment: Thank you for this Information. How i can change the Usage of permissions() in Access 2010 to fn_my_permissions?